# How book/specification authors do manage the same document in two versions: HTML and PDF?

Tags: conversion, html

Look at the example: http://www.r6rs.org/. Authors managed to provide two independent versions of the same content: one is in a singe PDF file (LaTeX rendered) and the second one in a well-structured (cross-referenced) HTML pages. I've seen that approach at least 3-5 times in some old 90s research works, books and compiler projects but I can't find any tools/manuals/information how they did that. Did I miss something?

If you're going to ask me why, the reason is that I need to write a specification that should be available in a high-quality LaTeX rendered PDF file, and at the same time, in HTML for web access.

[image]

Another example would be the book "*Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*":
**HTML version** (https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book.html), **PDF one** (https://web.mit.edu/alexmv/6.037/sicp.pdf).

Comment: there are several approaches (write in latex and convert to html, or write in a neutral format like pandoc/markdown and convert separately to html and latex) but for the one in your first sentence the page has a link to the source archive so you do not have to to guess: you have their exact sources.

Comment: similarly the mitpress link in your final paragraph, if you view source says `<!-- Generated from TeX source by tex2page, v 4o,      (c) Dorai Sitaram, http://www.cs.rice.edu/~dorai/tex2page -->` so it was written in latex and converted by the stated program.

Comment: Gorgeous! Just write it down adding two links: https://ds26gte.github.io/tex2page/index.html and the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texinfo. They are both what I exactly encountered through my 'whole' surfing history.

Comment: Feel free to self answer, I probably wouldn't use texinfo for new projects, the formatting is a lot more basic than available in latex. (also tex4ht and latexml far better known and more used latex to html convertors than tex2page, but that happened to be what the page you linked to had used)

Comment: for example of LaTeX document converted to HTML using TeX4ht see https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/tex4ht-doc.html . the document itself is work in progress draft, but I think it shows nicely what can be done with some custom configuration.